# "Bluetooth is turned off" and no on switch

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

After restarting once after I had some trouble with my monitors, Bluetooth does not work. There is no on/off switch and Bluetooth devices do not connect.

Screenshot wherein it says Bluetooth is off:

> [image]

It is as if my PC is trying to convince me that Bluetooth no longer exists. Not in the main settings, Not in the taskbar, nowhere.

Screenshot of the notification area where usually you can quickly turn on Bluetooth. Bluetooth is gone.

> [image]

I have updated my drivers multiple times. I have restarted my pc multiple times. Honestly I am at a loss. I have requested help from multiple of my friends, and none of them have found a solution for me.

Screenshot wherein Intel Wireless Bluetooth has a caution symbol next to it in the Device Manager:

> [image]

Comment: If you double-click the Device Manager item, what does it say?

Comment: @gronostaj in the "Device Status" box, it says "This device cannot start. (Code 10) STATUS_DEVICE_POWER_FAILURE"

Comment: Is this a laptop or a desktop? Does your WiFi work?

Comment: @gronostaj Desktop. Nothing is wrong with my WiFi at all, just Bluetooth

Comment: Try to shutdown the computer, disconnect power and physically disconnect the Bluetooth module. Then connect it again, connect power and turn on the computer.

Comment: After that Re-install the drivers if it does not work. It looks like your Bluetooth hardware is missing.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom It was working perfectly fine before a restart. I have already re-installed my drivers more than 4 times.

Comment: I meant to say uninstall. Create an Ubuntu Live USB and check if the Bluetooth will work. If it does not work, then the hardware is damaged.

Comment: @gronostaj where can the "Bluetooth module" be found and/or how can I identify it?

Comment: If you mean in Ubuntu, it's in the settings. Just search for Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Do a hard reset of the desktop. Press the power button hard when the computer is off. Then restart and the bluetooth will be back.

1. Perform a hard shut-down by holding the shift key is held down whilst selecting Windows Shut Down
2. Ensure your computer is unplugged
3. Hold down the power key for 93 seconds. That's 90, which is the maximum recommended elsewhere plus 3 to make sure it is over 90!
4. Press the power key briefly to start your computer
5. Allow it to start fully.

Comment: Can you at least explain the mechanism behind this “fix”? I’m very doubtful that this is a universal fix for bluetooth problems and it might introduce other problems.

Comment: My Lenovo laptop has this problem occuring sometimes when coming back after hypernation. I have no idea why it works. I will be happy if sombody gives an explanation.

Comment: @mohanraj This is not a valid fix for my issue. I have also done this, and it does not work. At least read my original post, please.

Comment: Yes I have read your original post. Your post does not mention whether you have done soft restart or hard restart, by pressing the power button. I gather that the hard reset corrects some conflict in the BIOS between Bluetooth and Wi-Fi adopter. If it does not solve your problem, enter BIOS disable the Wi-Fi adopter and then restart. After restart, uninstall and install Bluetooth driver. You should reenable the Wi-Fi adopter in BIOS afterwards(irrespective of weather your problem is solver or not).

Comment: I know this is an old post and reply but just wanted to say thanks, been using this for years for my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 and it fixes it every time.